# Find next cell from nearest blank cell in a column in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a problem in Excel like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 123 |  |
|  |  | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  | 456 |  |
|  |  | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  | 789 |  |
|  |  | 04/03/2021 |  |
|  |  | 04/03/2021 |  |

I want to add value to column B like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 123 |  |
|  | 123 | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  | 123 | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  | 123 | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  | 123 | 02/03/2021 |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  | 456 |  |
|  | 456 | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  | 456 | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  | 456 | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  | 456 | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  | 456 | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  | 456 | 03/03/2021 |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  | 789 |  |
|  | 789 | 04/03/2021 |  |
|  | 789 | 04/03/2021 |  |

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put your sample and expected output in table markdown format, you can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). I see you have sometimes 2 blank cells and sometimes just one, is it correct?

Comment: @DavidLeal yes, the number of blank cells is not a fixed number. I've already updated my question so that you can view easier!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no Excel version constraints as per tag listed in the question. You can try the following in cell `A2`:

```
=LET(B, B2:B19, idx, SCAN(0, B, LAMBDA(ac,bb, IF(bb<>"", ac+1,0))),
 seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(B)), MAP(seq, idx, LAMBDA(s,i, IF(i>1, INDEX(B, s-i+1),""))))
```

**Update**: As @VBasic2008 pointed out in the comment section, `MAP` call can be removed, taking advantage of `IF` array behavior, so the formula can be simplified as follows:

```
=LET(B, B2:B19, idx, SCAN(0, B, LAMBDA(ac,bb, IF(bb<>"", ac+1,0))), 
 IF(idx>1, INDEX(B, SEQUENCE(ROWS(B))-idx+1),""))
```

[image: excel output]

The name `idx`, counts the number of non blank elements within each group of values starting from `1`, and empty cells have the `0` value. The condition to fill with the first element start when `i>1` (second element of the group). The index position: `s-i+1` always points to the first element of the group.

We use `seq`, in `MAP` to avoid using `OFFSET` that is a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function) and instead we can use `INDEX`.

Comment: Sorry but my Excel version doesn't have SCAN and LAMBDA function. Can you have alternative solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your excel version?, please list it as part of your tags. Thanks

Comment: It's Office 16. And I also have Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, but cannot find those functions.

Comment: Great idea. Is there a reason behind using `MAP` since `IF(idx>1,INDEX(B,seq-idx+1),"")` works on its own?

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 true, I updated my answer with your simplification I gave you credit.

Comment: @HuyPhạmNhật thanks, I am not familiar with excel function available for Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise product. I had the impression the same excel functions as you have for O365, it is just a bundle of different Microsoft product by subscription. Do you know what function are available for your version or a link to function available for your version? Thanks

Comment: @HuyPhạmNhật check this link, maybe you have the same problem: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-to-lambda-functions-in-excel/be90c10e-85b9-4111-82d6-9e68fe69b674